# Packing / unpacking UUIDs in Ruby

Tags: ruby, uuid

If I have a UUID string like the following:

```
217aad3b-0b3d-4df0-a9ee-4fc9708f40bd
```

How do I pack that into a byte array (16 bytes) so that I can send it over HTTP as binary data?

Given the byte array, what is the function that unpacks it into a string like the one above?

Comment: I don't think that's possible: In ruby, chars are one byte a piece. ("puts 'a'.bytesize"). The UUID has 36 chars, so it will never fit in an 16 byte array.

Comment: Ruby defaults to UTF-8 now, so chars are multi-byte when they are necessary: `'é'.bytesize # => 2`. That probably won't help the OP though.

Comment: A UUID is a 128 bit value, not a string. A string representation of the UUID in hexadecimal might take up 36 bytes, but most of those bits are "wasted space." 128 bits/8 bits = 16 bytes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`Array.pack`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-pack) to pack your string:

First you need to turn it to array of 16-bit integers:

```
num_arr = "217aad3b-0b3d-4df0-a9ee-4fc9708f40bd".scan(/[0-9a-f]{4}/).map { |x| x.to_i(16) }
# => [8570, 44347, 2877, 19952, 43502, 20425, 28815, 16573]
```

Then pack it:

```
packed = num_arr.pack('n*')
# => "!z\xAD;\v=M\xF0\xA9\xEEO\xC9p\x8F@\xBD"
packed.bytesize
# => 16
```

`packed` is a string, but in Ruby byte arrays are represented as strings.

Comment: Note that the above, while a byte representation of a GUID, is not the correct byte representation of a GUID.  If you use C# to get the byte representation of the GUID with `Guid.Parse("217aad3b-0b3d-4df0-a9ee-4fc9708f40bd").ToByteArray().Select (b => b.ToString("X"))` you will notice that the bytes are 3B AD 7A 21 3D B F0 4D A9 EE 4F C9 70 8F 40 BD - in Ruby this would be `";\xADz!=\v\xF0M\xA9\xEEO\xC9p\x8F@\xBD"` - note that the above answer incorrectly packs the byte endian-ness if you're looking for a valid byte string to use when making API calls against the Win32 API for instance.